# Android build grade doesn't work

Tags: android, gradle, proxy

In my android studio,i enforce suddenly with this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Operation timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log).
```

i checked the internet connection and in terminal, i have ping for services.gradle.org

Comment: see this link https://teamtreehouse.com/community/gradle-project-refresh-fails-upon-starting-the-project

Answer (score 0):

you can use local gradle distribution under setting > build,execution,.. > gradle > and select local gradle distribution and provide path to gradle home.